# i have a problem in onActivated method in my code does not defined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsbML.png) `browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(this.tabsOnActivatedHandler);` , `chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(this.tabsOnActivatedHandler);` and  `browser.tabs.onActivatedChanged.addListener(this.tabsOnActivatedHandler);` all of this not defined what i should do to make page active

Comment: to have a better feedback from users please include formatted version of your code you are having issue with

Comment: Don't use `debugger` or breakpopints before the very first use of a `browser` or `chrome` namespace. This is a known bug in Chrome.